# Setting Carousel (Images) Height Equal to Window Height

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, blazor-webassembly

I have this page that loads a carousel but I want the carousel to fit in the window without having the vertical scrollbar as shown in the picture. How can I achieve that please?

Page:

```
<div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide"  data-bs-ride="carousel" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner rounded-corners">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="/images/carousel/carosel1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="carosel1">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h1 class="text-success fw-bold fst-italic font-monospace">Seamless Allocation of Subjects</h1>
                <p class="text-warning fst-italic">
                     ****************Some Text****************
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/carousel/carosel2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="carosel2">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h1 class="text-success fw-bold fst-italic font-monospace">Even Distribution of Classes</h1>
                <p class="text-warning fst-italic">
                    ****************Some Text****************

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/carousel/carosel3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="carosel3">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h1 class="text-success fw-bold fst-italic font-monospace">Class Management</h1>
                <p class="text-warning fst-italic">
                   ****************Some Text****************
               </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" id="#carouselIndicators-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" id="#carouselIndicators-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Current View:
[click to view the rendered view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Uig.jpg)

Comment: You could try to simplify this question for yourself and ask how to do this with a single image, or even a `<div>Hello</div>`. The solution will be the same for all cases.

Comment: Have a look here: [How to make a div 100% height of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window). Keep in mind you might need to take your menu into account, which is certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use slider height as calc attribute For example

```
height: calc(100vh - 0px); //Increase/decrease the value in pixel as needed
```

Then increase/decrease the value in pixels so that for every screen your slider will take windows height.
Let me know if this will work for you.